# use VirtualHost feature to share port 80?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ubuntu, virtualhost

My Ubuntu server has this in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/002-foosite

```
<VirtualHost 72.14.xxx.yyy:80>
    ServerName foosite.com
    ServerAlias www.foosite.com
    DocumentRoot /home/bar/public_html
    ServerAdmin bar@gmail.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Everytime I go to my server's port 80, I get the contents of /home/bar/public_html. But what I want to do is have more than one DocumentRoot based on the URL the user accesses. For example:

```
http://server/bar should go have DocumentRoot /home/bar/public_html
http://server/pligg should have DocumentRoot /srv/www/pligg
http://server/~blah should have DocumentRoot /home/blah/public_html
```

I'm sure this is not an uncommon setup, but I don't really understand the differences between Alias, VirtualHost, NameVirtualHost and all the other settings to configure this. 
How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

A [namevirtualhost](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html) is where you have different websites on different hostnames, but with the same ip address. For example, if server1.com and server2.com both had the same ip address, you would use a namevirtualhost for this.

Virtualhosts can also be seperated by [ip addresses](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/ip-based.html), in the case that server1.com and server2.com had different addresses.

An [alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html) would be used in the case of the http://server/pligg example which you posted, to link a directory that is otherwise elsewhere located (usually outside the document root). Inside a <VirtualHost> container the alias will apply just for that virtualhost. If placed outside it the alias will work for all virtualhosts.

```
Alias /pligg/ "/srv/www/pligg/"

<Directory "/srv/www/pligg">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

http://server/~blah, where blah is a user and the location is in blah's home directory should be confgured with [userdir](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_userdir.html). To enable userdir (on debian/ubuntu apache) you can use the 'a2enmod' script eg. a2enmod user_dir.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it

```
<VirtualHost 72.14.xxx.yyy:80>
  ServerName foosite.com
  ServerAlias www.foosite.com
  DocumentRoot /home/bar/public_html
  Alias /bar/ /home/bar/public_html
  Alias /pligg/ /srv/www/pligg
  Userdir public_html
  ServerAdmin bar@gmail.com
</VirtualHost>
```

For the alias command, see the [mod_alias docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html). For the ~ magic, see the [mod_userdir docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_userdir.html) or this [public html howto](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/public_html.html).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the Alias directive gives this message in the error_log:

[Mon Jul 06 20:48:58 2009] [error] [client 76.79.xxx.yyy] File does not exist: /home/bar/public_html/pligg

Looks like it's still thinking "inside" /home/bar/public_html - something else I can try?